# VBA for password does not continue after password was entered in text field

Tags: excel, vba

In my spreadsheet I have a button that is linked to the following VBA:

```
Sub Button_01()
If UserForm1.checkPassword() = True Then
Sheet1.Range("C3").Value = 1
Else
End If
End Sub
```

With this button I trigger a user form which has the following VBA:

```
Private passwordStatus As Boolean

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim a As String
    Dim Password As String
    a = "123"
    Password = TextBox1.Text
    passwordStatus = False
    If Password = a Then
        MsgBox "Password Correct.", vbInformation
        passwordStatus = True
        Unload Me
    Else
        MsgBox "Password Incorrect. Please try again.", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub

Function checkPassword() As Boolean
  UserForm1.Show
  checkPassword = passwordStatus
End Function
```

The `UserForm1` opens without any issue but when I enter a password into the userform the process does not continue. `The UserForm1` just stays there.

I cannot find the mistake in my code that blocks the macro from continuing after I entered the password. Can you help me?

Comment: Your code works for me also (but there is another problem. See JvdV answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me your code works perfectly, apart from:

```
Sub Button_01()
If UserForm1.checkPassword() = True Then
Sheet1.Range("C3").Value = 1
Else
End If
End Sub
```

This piece of code will error out.

Change:

```
Sheet1.Range("C3").Value = 1
```

To:

```
Sheets(1).Range("C3").Value = 1
```

- Clicking on a button on the sheet with Button_01 assigned to it will open the userform1.
- On the opened userform I can click OptionButton1 and it will run it's click_event
- If I have "123" typed in textbox1 it will hide the userform, a wrong password triggers a msgbox to retry.

Comment: Hi JvdV, thanks a lot for your answer. I figured out why it was not working on my site. I copied the UserForm code from another spreadsheet and somehow forgot to insert the CommandButton1 on the UserForm.

Answer (score 1):

Passing information between a userform and a regular module is normally done via public variables. You should put the bulk of your code in the regular module, and only use the userform to pass the check back.

Regular module:

```
Public CorrectPassword As Boolean

Sub Button_01()
    CorrectPassword  = False
    UserForm1.Show
    If CorrectPassword = True Then
        Sheets(1).Range("C3").Value = 1
    Else
        Msgbox "Password Incorrect. Please try again.", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

Userform module:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim a As String
    Dim Password As String
    a = "123"
    Password = TextBox1.Text
    If Password = a Then CorrectPassword = True
    Unload Me
End Sub
```